# sequence size must match size of the row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am looking for some help on proper syntax in ArcGIS Pro/ Python 3. I am trying to read data from a feature class and write to another feature class. The attribute fields are different so I am reading from source and assigning it to output. I get this error at `insertCursor.insertRow(newRow)`:

> sequence size must match size of the row

```
def LoadData(fSource, fTarget):

    # setup search cursor
    fields = ['*']

    fldShape = "SHAPE@"

    # target field mapping 
    fldCountry = 'Country'
    fldCommodity = "Product"
    constructionYear = "CNSTR_YEAR"

    try: 
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fTarget, ['*']) as insertCursor:
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fSource, "*") as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    country = row[cursor.fields.index(fldCountry)]
                    geometry = row[cursor.fields.index(fldShape)]
                    commodity = row[cursor.fields.index(fldCommodity)]
                    constructionYear = row[cursor.fields.index(constructionYear)]
                    
                    newRow = [country, geometry, commodity, constructionYear]

                    insertCursor.insertRow(newRow)


    except Exception:
            print(e.args[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question to include the error message as formatted text?

Comment: The first rule of using column list wildcards with DA cursors is "Don't do it!"  If you specify the exact columns you want to insert and query, you're less likely to have imbalanced list lengths (query adds the length and/or area columns).

Comment: List the fields first for the insert- and searchcursor then make sure they list the correct fields and are the same length. For example instead of `arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fTarget, ['*'])` try `icurlist = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fTarget)` then use the list in:  `arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fTarget, icurlist)` and same logic for the searchcursor